# python - Why do I get this Key Error:0 when using random.choice()?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a randomizer function to select random participants into a game. Basically my logic is:

1. randomly select 1 name from dataframe column (using random.choice())
2. black out that name by replacing it with NaN
3. re-run

For my 2nd run, I am getting Key Error: 0 when using random.choice method. I can correct it by making it into a list using tolist().

Let me illustrate what I mean by following codes:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from random import choice

df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Andy', 'Jack', 'Anne']})
for i in range(1,100):
    c_name = choice(df.name.dropna())
df.name.replace(c_name, np.NaN, inplace=True) #Let's say Andy is replaced

# up until here it will work fine

# Trying the 2nd run

for i in range(1,100):
    c_name = choice(df.name.dropna())
# !will output Key Error : 0
# if I do this: c_name = choice(df.name.dropna().tolist()) it will be fine.
# if the NaN value is at the last index, it is also fine.
```

My question is why `random.choice()` behaves like this? I have dropped the NaN value using dropna(), it should act as a Series of names without NaN.

Comment: Why not use sample?
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html 
Should do what you want in one go

Comment: This is another great solution. No reason why, I didnt know there is a sample function. Still I would like to know why `random.choice()` is behaving that way.

Comment: Without running your code: Why do you run your loops 100 times to get one name? c_name will always be the result of the last loop.
I am not sure how choice combined with a dataframe behaves. I knows how to work with lists though - that is probably the differencer

Comment: I dont have a problem using `choice` with list. It is usually working fine with dataframe & series. That is why I am confused with this behavior. And yes, I loop it 100 times to simulate randomness even further. (And also I use this in my printing animation ie. overwriting current lines with another name). I will get the last name choice it randomized.

Comment: Both part are working completely fine for me. Are you using the latest version of pandas?

Comment: If you are getting an error, *post the full error message, including the stack trace*

Comment: @chrisckwong821 if you got the last name (Anne in this case) and set the last index to NaN, there will be no problem. My python version is `3.6.1`. My pandas version is `0.20.3`.

Answer (score 2):

The first error is:

> result = self.index.get_value(self, key)

Since random.choice takes a sequence:

> random.choice(seq) Return a random element from the non-empty sequence
>   seq. If seq is empty, raises IndexError.

so given a dataframe it would implicitly change the df into a list by each index. It throws an error if the index is not continuous.

Comment: Thanks! However, if converting df-into-list is creating error when the index is not continuous, why am I able to append `.tolist()` function to convert it into a list just fine? Is it because `random.choice` is creating a sequence (which I guess must be consecutive in nature) instead of an ordinary list?